# Capturing panic() in golang

Tags: logging, go, panic

We have a large-ish golang application that uses the logger (actually, a custom logger), to write output to a log file that is periodically rotated.

However, when an application crashes or panic()'s, those messages go to standard error.

Is there any way to override the panic functionality to use our logger?

Comment: I think `recover` is better than redirect the output. `debug.PrintStack` can print the logs of you need. Some other logs, for example, the GC message, can still stay in the stderr.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't redirect the output from panic away from standard error, or to your logger.  The best thing you can do is redirect standard error to a file which you can do externally, or inside your program.

For my [rclone](http://github.com/ncw/rclone) program I redirected standard error to capture everything to a file on an option which is unfortunately isn't particularly easy to do in a cross platform way.  Here is how I did it (see the redirect*.go files)

For linux/unix

```
// Log the panic under unix to the log file

//+build unix

package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

// redirectStderr to the file passed in
func redirectStderr(f *os.File) {
    err := syscall.Dup2(int(f.Fd()), int(os.Stderr.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to redirect stderr to file: %v", err)
    }
}
```

and for windows

```
// Log the panic under windows to the log file
//
// Code from minix, via
//
// http://play.golang.org/p/kLtct7lSUg

//+build windows

package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

var (
    kernel32         = syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    procSetStdHandle = kernel32.MustFindProc("SetStdHandle")
)

func setStdHandle(stdhandle int32, handle syscall.Handle) error {
    r0, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procSetStdHandle.Addr(), 2, uintptr(stdhandle), uintptr(handle), 0)
    if r0 == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            return error(e1)
        }
        return syscall.EINVAL
    }
    return nil
}

// redirectStderr to the file passed in
func redirectStderr(f *os.File) {
    err := setStdHandle(syscall.STD_ERROR_HANDLE, syscall.Handle(f.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to redirect stderr to file: %v", err)
    }
    // SetStdHandle does not affect prior references to stderr
    os.Stderr = f
}
```

Comment: This worked for me -- panics going to my fd instead of stderr solved my issue.

Comment: I tried this and the unix side worked for me but the windows side did not... any insight? -- https://play.golang.org/p/jQaN1bNypx

Comment: I did some more experimenting and on window's you must also do `os.Stderr = f` since `SetStdHandle` does not affect the prior reference to stderr. On unix it is not necessary since the `Dup2` does affect the prior reference to stderr. https://play.golang.org/p/mXjw6lOrG9

Comment: See Jakob's answer down below.  If you're on a POSIX-like or BSD-like supported by Go, this will work.  I'm currently working with him to see if we can clean up some of the results of this so that logging is more consistent, etc. for gocryptfs.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect entire stderr to file in windows? I am trying this for all the messages, but it only puts the panic to the file. I am able to redirect all STDOUT but not error. @TimLewis

Comment: On Windows I think you can simplify by using:
windows.SetStdHandle(windows.STD_ERROR_HANDLE, windows.Handle(f.Fd()))

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`recover()`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics) to recover panics from the same goroutine. When calling `recover()` in a deferred method (remember that deferred methods will still be called, even when `panic()`ing), it will return whatever was passed into the last `panic()` call as argument (or `nil` when the program is not panicking).

```
defer func() {
    if x := recover(); x != nil {
        // recovering from a panic; x contains whatever was passed to panic()
        log.Printf("run time panic: %v", x)

        // if you just want to log the panic, panic again
        panic(x)
    }
}()

panic("foo");
```

**Note however**, that you cannot recover from panics that were triggered in a different goroutine (thanks to JimB for the hint). Using a single `recover()` to recover from panics from any goroutine is not possible.

Comment: I would note that you can only recover from within your own goroutine. I think OP may be looking for a global "recover", which you can't do.

Comment: True, indeed. I'll edit that in, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Well, I don't need to stop the panic, I just want the backtrace to appear in my log, not to stderr.  I guess I could replace os.Stderr with my logger?  

Nope -- just checked, even with os.Stderr being my logfile handle, the panic still goes to stderr.

Comment: keep in mind that calling `panic(x)`, even in recovery, will kill your process. if you just want the stack, call `debug.PrintStack()`

Comment: That's just what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Expanding @nick-craig-wood's answer:
If you are on Linux you can spawn a logger(1) instance and redirect stderr to it. That way you get the full backtrace into syslog. This is what [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs) does:

```
// redirectStdFds redirects stderr and stdout to syslog; stdin to /dev/null
func redirectStdFds() {
    // stderr and stdout
    pr, pw, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Warn.Printf("redirectStdFds: could not create pipe: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    tag := fmt.Sprintf("gocryptfs-%d-logger", os.Getpid())
    cmd := exec.Command("logger", "-t", tag)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = pr
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Warn.Printf("redirectStdFds: could not start logger: %v\n", err)
    }
    pr.Close()
    err = syscall.Dup2(int(pw.Fd()), 1)
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Warn.Printf("redirectStdFds: stdout dup error: %v\n", err)
    }
    syscall.Dup2(int(pw.Fd()), 2)
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Warn.Printf("redirectStdFds: stderr dup error: %v\n", err)
    }
    pw.Close()

    // stdin
    nullFd, err := os.Open("/dev/null")
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Warn.Printf("redirectStdFds: could not open /dev/null: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    err = syscall.Dup2(int(nullFd.Fd()), 0)
    if err != nil {
        tlog.Warn.Printf("redirectStdFds: stdin dup error: %v\n", err)
    }
    nullFd.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updating for 2023. `syscall.SysCall` is deprecated so I was looking for an alternative for capturing panics on Windows. Andrew McKinlay's answer worked great for me. Here's what I'm using to capture panics and send to a log file

```
func redirectStderr(logPath string) {
    logFile, _ := os.OpenFile(logPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_SYNC|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    defer logFile.Close()

    err := windows.SetStdHandle(windows.STD_ERROR_HANDLE, windows.Handle(logFile.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        Log.Fatalf("Failed to redirect stderr to file: %v", err)
    }
    os.Stderr = logFile
}
```

p.s. Rclone is an awesome tool!

Comment: This is working fine. Note that if the main goroutine panics, it won't be logged unless you don't close the handle.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [gopls v0.15.0-pre.3](https://github.com/golang/tools/releases/tag/gopls%2Fv0.15.0-pre.3) (Feb. 2024):

> The v1.23 release of Go expected in August contains a feature that makes it possible for a Go program to monitor itself for unexpected crashes of any kind. When gopls is built with the latest Go toolchain, it will enable this feature and save crash reports into the local telemetry database.

It refers to:

> ### [Issue #42888 `runtime/debug`: add `SetCrashOutput(file *os.File)`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42888)
>
> Currently there are difficulties with nicely capturing crash output from Go programs. Crashes print to stderr, however, usually both stdout and stderr are used by programs for other purposes. While it's not wrong to output it to stderr, it mixes two outputs together making later separation more difficult.
>
> Capturing crashes is useful for post-mortem debugging and sending reports. Of course, due to unknown crashed program state using a custom callback is understandably dangerous.
>
> A simpler alternative would be to allow changing file descriptor where to print crashes. In the simplest form it could look like:
>
> ```golang
> package main
> import "runtime/debug"
>
> func init(){
>   debug.SetCrashOutputFD(3)
> }
> ```
>
> This would allow passing in a `fd` for separate file, pipe to another "crash monitor" process or connect to an external server.

See [CL 547978](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/547978), and its [associated example](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/548121/16/src/runtime/debug/example_monitor_test.go).

So for Go 1.23 (Q3 2024).