# Write result stack trace default to file

Tags: logging, go, stack-trace

I use logger in my program defined from pattern as below

```
var (
    logFile *os.File
    Info    *log.Logger
)

func init() {
    var err error
    logFile, err = os.OpenFile("/my/file/with.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot open log file error:%s. Program was terminated.", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    Info = log.New(logFile,
        "INFO: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
 }
```

Now I would like write all information from stackTrace if these occured for example from `panic()`  to my log file. Now if some gone was wrong all this information are print to console in my IDE, but if porgram works on server, I lose information if occured some null pointer, wrong pass argument to function, that's why I want write this information to log file.
It is possible ?

Comment: You should be redirecting stderr and stdout to a file on the server (or into some other logging mechanism). You set `os.Stderr` to another file in your app, but it's going to be more reliable to have that managed externally.

Comment: This is a key. A tried find some function to this in golang doc, but for now nothing. A tried for eg `os.Stderr = os.NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stderr), "/my/log/file.log")`  but dosen't works. I will be trying still something other... unles someone will be faster, and find solution before me

Comment: `os.NewFile` just returns a new `*os.File` with that file descriptor, so it did nothing except change string returned by `os.Stderr.Name()`

Comment: I found solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772012/capturing-panic-in-golang this I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use syscall.Dup2 to link the opened file to the standard stream

```
func main() {
   syscall.Dup2(int(logFile.Fd()), 2)
}
```

or create panic handler

```
defer func() {
        err := recover()
        if err != nil {
            //...
        }
    }()
```

Comment: You can't create a "global panic handler", because you can only recover within the panicking goroutine.