# GO + Windows NT Service, how do I capture a panic from 3rd party?

Tags: windows, go, windows-services

I'm trying to capture a panic that's occurring in my NT service. I know it's dumped to stderr, but how can I capture to a log or even eventviewer?
I know that I can capture my panic's by using defer/recover - but that doesn't work for when a panic is thrown in another library.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like a windows administration question -- How does _any_ NT service capture stderr?

Comment: @JimB That's a fair point!

Comment: Is [redirecting to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34773942/11810946) an option?

Comment: What package/library are you using to run your app as a service? or are you creating a binary and just running it as a service?

Comment: Have the system write a minidump when your service crashes. It's like a log, but useful.